# How to make multiple threads do work on a single TStringList

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I want to be able to make multiple threads do work on a single `TStringList`. This is my current Thread code for using a single thread to do the work;

```
type
  TFilterThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    lCombos : TStringList;
    //Public Vars
  end;

procedure TFilterThread.Execute;
var
  I: integer;
  HTML: String;
  frm1 : TForm1;
  splitLogin: TStringList;
  validCount: Integer;
begin
  validCount := 0;
  for I := 0 to lCombos.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if Terminated then Exit();
      Unit1.Form1.ListBox1.ItemIndex := i;
      try
        HTML := Unit1.Form1.IdHTTP1.Get(EmailCheckURL + lCombos[i]);
        if AnsiPos('You indicated you', HTML) > 0 then
        begin
          //Do stuff
        end;

      except
        Continue;
      end;
    end;
    Showmessage('Finished!');
    Unit1.Form1.Button1.Caption := 'Start';
end;
```

To Start the thread I use;

```
lComboLsit := TStringList.Create;
for I := 0 to listBox1.Items.Count -1 do
    lComboLsit.Add(listBox1.Items[i]);`

iTFilterThread := TFilterThread.Create(True);
iTFilterThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
iTFilterThread.lCombos := lComboLsit;

iTFilterThread.Start;
```

How would I introduce another thread to also do work on the `lCombos` list so that the operation would complete quicker?

Comment: You put a lock over the list, such as a critical section. *every* attempt to do anything with it (no matter what thread) must lock it prior to working with it, and unlock it when it's finished. This is the basic concept of thread-protecting.

Comment: There's an answer to a (not very good) question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11547928) that should get you started.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=2167

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that it depends. If the string list is not modified, then there's nothing to do. If the string list is modified then what is best depends critically on your specific usage.

Looking at your code, your program may not be CPU bound and so adding more threads may not help. Your program's bottleneck will the HTTP communication. However, despite not being CPU bound it is plausible that running multiple threads will reduce the impact HTTP latency. You can benchmark to find out. You don't appear to be modifying the string list so there's no race problems to be concerned with there.

However, here's a problem:

```
Unit1.Form1.IdHTTP1.Get(EmailCheckURL + lCombos[i]);
```

That will work, and is thread safe so long as `TIdHTTP` is thread safe. But it's pretty ugly to allow a thread to access a component on a form like that. And I don't see any real sense or need to share the `TIdHTTP` instance between threads. It would be far cleaner to let each thread instantiate and use their own `TIdHTTP` component.

Of course, you will need to decide on a policy for dividing the work between all your threads. You could have a shared index that keeps track of the next item to process. Have each thread increment it atomically each time they take an item. A parallel for loop would be a good fit here. That's available in the latest version of Delphi, or in any decent third party parallel library.

You do have some problems with your code. In the thread procedure you do this:

```
Unit1.Form1.ListBox1.ItemIndex := i;
....
Unit1.Form1.Button1.Caption := 'Start';
```

You cannot access VCL components from a thread.

And then you do this

```
ShowMessage('Finished!');
```

Don't show UI from a thread.

A point of idiom. Instead of looping over the items in your list box you can simply do this:

```
lComboLsit.Assign(listBox1.Items);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Very helpful. If I was using a shared global variable with `CriticalSections`, how would I solve the problem of not looping through every item in the `listbox`? If I increase the counter by 1 at the end of each loop, then for exampe, if I use 5 threads, 5 items in the listbox won't get checked.

Comment: I wouldn't use critical sections. I'd have a shared index, a shared list, and atomically increment the index. Perhaps using a stride to avoidd false sharing.

Comment: Wondeful, I didn't know about atomic incrementing. Bit of research and I've come up with a working solution. Many thanks

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on what a "stride" is and "false sharing"?

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/understanding-and-avoiding-memory-issues/212400410

Comment: Thanks, very technical read. One more question! If I have a shared index, lets say `iIndex` and at the beginning of each iteration of the thread, I pick the `iIndex` of the shared array `sharedArray[iIndex]`, and immediately after I do `AtomicIncrement(iIndex)`, how would I check that all the iterations are complete, and I won't get an out of bounds errors? Also how would I check that exactly all the items have been checked?

Comment: If the value returned by AtomicIncrement is off the end, there are no tasks left